# PHP PDO - Showing password when too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Whenever my website receives too many connections, it's showing my database information.

I have specifically told PDO not to show any error messages with `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database['db'];
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $database['user'], $database['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));       
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT); // <== add this line
//echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';
```

Furthermore I have disabled PHP errors:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

Why is my PDO showing my sensitive database information to everyone when there are too many connections?

Comment: what exactly is shown ?

Comment: @Dagon "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections" and then my database information.

Comment: Well, I am still learning PDO, and would very much like another approach to my issue.

Comment: First of all, never set error mode to silent. You always want errors to log. But they shouldn't display, so you can shut that off (I would do it globally using php.ini or .htaccess, though. Aside from that, you should also consider using exception handling for queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you're trying to connect to the database **BEFORE** you set the silent attribute. So during the connection attempt, PDO is still free to scream as loudly as it wants. You need to specify silent as part of the connection attempt itself:

```
$dbh = new PDO($[..snip..], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Gives me this error: Warning: PDO::__construct(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class

Comment: That would be `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` instead of `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`.

Comment: yeah, bad cut&paste. change `,` to `=>` for the errmode. Answer fixed.